# Random.choice to return and fill null values equally

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to fill all the null values with random choices made from a list using:

```
new_df = new_df.fillna(new_df.loc[new_df['rest_type'] == 'Cafe' ,'dish_liked'].fillna(random.choice(top5C)))
```

Here is the list, for example :

```
top5C = ['Pasta', 'Waffles', 'Mocktails', 'Coffee', 'BrownieChocolate', 'Burgers']
```

The problem is, it's just picking up 1 random value from the list and filling the entire column with that value, which is not what I'm trying to do. How can I evenly distribute all values inside the list randomly in all the null values? Thanks

Edit :

Here's how my new_df looks like :

[image]

Edit :
(Reason : Tried what the people have suggested)

I've tried lambda function to fill the null value as follows :

```
new_df.loc[new_df['rest_type'] == 'Quick Bites' ,'dish_liked'].map(lambda x: random.choice(top5) if pd.isnull(x) else x)
```

But this just returns the output of :

```
new_df.loc[new_df['rest_type'] == 'Quick Bites' ,'dish_liked'] and not filling any null values.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Edited: I had entirely neglected the fact that the column containing NaN is of type string. Answer updated to use pd.isnull instead of np.isnan

How about this, where I use the pandas `map` method together with some numpy functions and your `random.choice` to infill only where we have NaN:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

top5C = ['Pasta', 'Waffles', 'Mocktails', 'Coffee', 'BrownieChocolate', 'Burgers']

df=pd.DataFrame(data={"a":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"b":[11,12,13,14,15,16],"c":["sausage",np.NaN,"pie",np.NaN,"fried egg",np.NaN]})
```

This gives the following starting dataframe:

```
>>> df
   a   b          c
0  1  11    sausage
1  2  12        NaN
2  3  13        pie
3  4  14        NaN
4  5  15  fried egg
5  6  16        NaN
```

Then we infill by:

```
df["c"]= df["c"].map(lambda x: random.choice(top5C) if pd.isnull(x) else x)
```

giving, for instance:

```
>>> df
   a   b                 c
0  1  11           sausage
1  2  12            Coffee
2  3  13               pie
3  4  14         Mocktails
4  5  15         fried egg
5  6  16  BrownieChocolate
```

*PS: The edit I have made here is to use the `pd.isnull()` method instead of `np.isnan()`, because `np.isnan()` doesn't act on strings, but the pandas method does. Sorry about that!*

Now, this infills with random choices from the list, but it does not guarantee that each item in your list will only be chosen once, which I am inferring from your saying "evenly distribute", but I am picking random items from the list.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this "new_df.loc[new_df['rest_type'] == 'Cafe' ,'dish_liked'].map(lambda x: random.choice(top5C) if np.isnan(x) else x)" but getting an error "ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"

Comment: I think that to go any further we'll need to see what your new_df dataframe looks like. Can you edit your question to show an example, with some code to create a small version of it?

Comment: I've updated the main post. please check. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I had completely ignored the fact that your field is of type string rather than being a number. np.isnan acts on numbers but not strings, so I have edited my answer to use the pandas method pd.isnull, which will act on strings to find NaN.

Comment: Thanks I tried this but maybe there is some issue and this is not working as well. It would be helpful if you could look at the main post as I've edited it. Thanks again

Comment: In the statement you are using, it looks like you are not storing the output back into a column. In my answer I use df["c"] = df["c"].map( etc etc etc ), which passes the result of the map function back into the column. In your statement it looks like you are just calling the new_df.loc[] etc etc without storing the result.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please show me the way how can I do that for my case please ?

Comment: Bumping after a long time to get a solution. Thanks

Comment: Bump. Please still stucked on it

Comment: Hello, sorry for my delay over Christmas and so on. What you need to do is create the new data and then assign it back to your existing column that you want to update, or you can assign it to a new column. I think that to go any further, you need to provide some code that creates some example data of exactly the same kind as your example dataframe. The image of your dataframe is fairly useful, but not as useful as some code that produces the same rows that you are showing.